# Como retornar el valor que tenia una columna anterior

Tags: select, variables, condiciones, sql, cursor

me surge una duda producto de una consulta que esta realizando un amigo a una base de datos de su trabajo.

Resulta ser que la tabla `EMPLEADO_ACC_PER` registra los cambios que tiene un empleado en la nomina de la institución, en esta tabla se registra el código del empleado, código acción, código puesto.

El detalle es que no todas las acciones que se realizan, registran el código de puesto, dejando el campo con el prefijo NA, lo cual al buscar en la tabla de puesto retorna un `NULL`.

Mi amigo deseo generar un reporte con la información de cada una de estas acciones de personal, pero en los registros que el puesto es NA retorna `NULL` lógicamente, la pregunta es:

Puedo generar un `select` en el cual estos campos que retornan `NULL` muestren el puesto que tenia antes de esa acción de personal

Esta es la consulta:

```
select a.empleado,b.nombre,
c.descripcion, 
a.fecha_rige,
a.salario_promedio, 
d.descripcion as Puesto, 
a.departamento
from INTUR.EMPLEADO_ACC_PER a inner join
INTUR.EMPLEADO B ON a.empleado=b.empleado INNER JOIN
INTUR.tipo_accion c on a.tipo_accion=c.tipo_accion left outer join
INTUR.puesto d on a.puesto=d.puesto
where a.empleado = '33231'
ORDER BY b.nombre, a.fecha_rige
```

Lo que se desea es que los campos `NULL` tomen el ultimo valor en no nulo, en este caso "OPERARIO TEMPORAL"

Espero su ayuda

Comment: Lo que se quiere hacer parece no corresponder a la realidad de los datos. ¿Por qué debería asociar los que tengan `NA` con el anterior? ¿Por qué esos registros no quedan relacionados y hay que ponerles `NA`?  Parecería que se quiere recurrir a una acción truculenta (y peligrosa por el lío que se podría armar en los datos por un error de orden por ejemplo) para resolver un problema que está a otro nivel, quizá en el diseño mismo del modelo de datos o en la lógica que crea los registros.

Comment: La función LAG puede ser de utilidad. Lo que hace esta función es acceder a la información de registros anteriores. Cuéntanos sobre qué motor estás haciendo estas consultas para entender si la función puede funcionar.